# Chrome auto-fill and login

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, password-management, automatic-logon

Is there a way how to automatically log-in on pages which have saved name and password in Chrome? The credentials are automatically filled in the form, but I still have to hit enter or click a button.

I tried to use UserJS, but when I simulate click on the button or submit the form, it's sent empty (security measurement). Is possible to do this beside storing the password somewhere else and handling everything by completely custom UserJS?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can auto-fill the logon forms, but generally leave it up to the
user to verify the information and click the button. This is because
of security concerns.

Auto-login is rather the domain of password-handling extensions such
as LastPass (free for one computer).
However, there aren't many that do that. For example,
the biggest competitor to LastPass, BitWarden, doesn't have this option.

Note that auto-login won't work for websites that use Captcha.